# Got some problem with math

Tags: mathematics

First of all sorry, if this is the wrong place to post this, didn't found a better tag for it.

So I used to be/am quite good in math, however recently I discovered a big weakness I have.
Whenever I learn something in a given topic, I can answer the related questions well, I know how to use the given formulas etc. 
However when we do tests involving 4-5 similar topics, I can hardly find out- sometimes can't- which formulas to use at which exercises.
I start a given exercise, which should be solved with formula 'x', and then later on after wasting at least 5 minuites, I realise I should've used formula 'y' to solve it.

Is there any way I could fix this? What should I do against this? It's really irritating sometimes... It's not even that I can't memorise the formulas, It's just that I can't identify which one to use when.

Regards.

Comment: What kind of student are you? (Undergraduate? Graduate? High school?) Note that this site is for people in academia at the graduate level or higher (or undergrads who have problems similar to what a graduate student may have). Your question sounds like it may not fit that description and may be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia.

Comment: No doubt there are resources on the internet that can teach you how to approach a problem, or perhaps you could ask your teacher / professor for some suggestions on how to improve. Another site, such as physicsforums, might be a better fit for the question – though you should try to elaborate with some examples as it's currently very broad and unclear.

Comment: I'd suggest asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/.  Definitely off-topic.

Comment: I was very tempted to close, but I think even postgrads can face this problem. Plus, the solution/book I'm recommending has been discussed on a few occasions on this forum, which makes me think that the question may be borderline acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to re-think how you approach analytical problems. I suggest you read [G. Polya's How To solve It](https://books.google.ie/books?id=SaMXnwEACAAJ&dq=polya%20how%20to%20solve%20it&hl=ga&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZxK7i9rjKAhVCGg4KHTRuAnQQ6AEIIzAB). The book is mostly written as dialogues between teacher and student, but those dialogues are very similar to the inner dialogue you have (or should have) when you try to solve problems involving formulas or analysis. It's a good book for anyone from high school age to postgrad.